# Difference between two integrals with PDFs

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate $$\int_{E'}^{\bar{v}}(v-c)g(v)dv-\int_{E'}^{\bar{v}}(v-E')g(v)dv$$ where $v$ is a random variable with support $[\underline{v}, \bar{v}]$, and $c<E'$ (both of which are in $[\underline{v},\bar{v}]$). Is it acceptable to ignore the pdfs (as they are the same in each term) and simply treat the problem as one with two linear functions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrals have the same boundaries so we can write them as one integral:
$$\int\limits_{E'}^{\bar{v}}(v-c)g(v)\mathrm{d}v-\int\limits_{E'}^{\bar{v}}(v-E')g(v)\mathrm{d}v
=\int\limits_{E'}^{\bar{v}}(v-c)g(v)-(v-E')g(v)\,\mathrm{d}v$$
Factoring $g$ out yields
$$\int\limits_{E'}^{\bar{v}}\Big[(v-c)-(v-E')\Big]g(v)\,\mathrm{d}v=\int\limits_{E'}^{\bar{v}}\Big[E'-c\Big]g(v)\,\mathrm{d}v.$$